# display blob in img tag (javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blob

I'm getting a blob file from mySql and It looks like the image below.

[image]

and I'd like to show this image through `<img src={imagefile}/>` (I'm using React.js).

How can I the blob file to url link?
I tried `URL.createObjectURL(imagefile)`

but It gives me an error that
`Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided`

please Help ToT

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to convert you data to base64 by using the folowing code, then use can use Base64 in your img tag **< img src="yourbase64here"/>**

```
let base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(data)));
```

Comment: Will not work in most cases, the src tag will get very long for images and browsers like firefox will not show the image on phones. which is understandable as you get a src field with millions of characters long.